# IP Cam (RTSP) Stream transcoded with wowza and embeded in a website

Tags: html, video, wowza, ip-camera

I am having problems configuring following case:
My Customer would like to have his Surveillance Cameras embeded to a Website. The webpage and the livestreams should be accessible by any Device and Browser without using plugins.

I have tried following with wowza:

```
Incoming Stream is: rtsp://172.17.27.62/media/video1 (Sony Ipela CH140)
Transcoding: Transrate (Default)

source  mp4:${SourceStreamName}_source  
720p    mp4:${SourceStreamName}_720p    
360p    mp4:${SourceStreamName}_360p    
240p    mp4:${SourceStreamName}_240p    
160p    mp4:${SourceStreamName}_160p
```

I can watch the streams without problems in wowza test players. I see that they are being watched with flash player.

I try to embed the transcoded streams with following html5 code on my local xampp (apache):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="http://localhost:1935/Surveillance/ngrp:test.stream_all/manifest.f4m" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="http://localhost:1935/Surveillance/ngrp:test.stream_all/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="http://localhost:1935/Surveillance/ngrp:test.stream_all/Manifest" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="http://localhost:1935/Surveillance/ngrp:test.stream_all/manifest.mpd" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause() { 
    if (myVideo.paused) 
        myVideo.play(); 
    else 
        myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig() { 
    myVideo.width = 560; 
} 

function makeSmall() { 
    myVideo.width = 320; 
} 

function makeNormal() { 
    myVideo.width = 420; 
} 
</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

none of them work in latest chrome browser. 
Can I configure the wowza transcoding in to [mp4 supported format in html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)?
What would be the next steps to reach my goal?

Regards Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wowza output formats are not supported in HTML5 across all browsers and devices.
See: [Wowza Blog - A Note on HTML5](http://www.wowza.com/blog/a-note-on-html5)

They recommend using JWPlayer which provides fall-backs for all browsers. Note that HLS on desktop is available only in the Premium player. See [JWPlayer - Using HLS Streaming](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430218-using-hls-streaming)

[Wowza - How to use JWPlayer with the Wowza Streaming Engine](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?484-How-to-use-JW-Player-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine) 
as recommended on the [support forum](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?37382-HTML5-Live-streaming).

And your `type`'s are wrong. Example: HLS has `type="application/x-mpegURL"` and so on.

Comment: Thx a lot aergistal. So mobile devices support JWPlayer?

Comment: Yes. Actually for iOS and Android 4+ it'll play the stream directly in HTML5 (JWPlayer only provides a fallback such as Flash if the video doesn't play natively). You can check http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403653-browser-device-reference#fallback

Comment: You will have problems if you need to stream to older mobile devices.